# Campo de texto igual do facebook

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-activity

alguem sabe como deixar o campo se inserir texto igual ao do facebook ?
Preciso que meu texto fique igual. Quando copio e colo a cifra da musica no facebook, ele fica igual ao site. Mas se colo no meu aplicativo, ele fica errado.
Ja tentei com Multline Text, plain text, mas nenhum fica igual. Alguem tem ideia de como é feito? Como deixo meu campo de texto igual do facebook para o texto ficar igual da pagina copiada

Do facebook quando colo a cifra da musica
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como fica no meu app
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]